# SSIS Logging detail from SP with Full Result Set

Tags: sql-server, ssis

(I am not a vested enough member to include screen shots in my post - here is a link to a shared OneDrive folder which has article with images to explain better https://1drv.ms/f/s!Ai9bJ2dV87SLg9h5FP84If74hyUK4Q)

I am trying to log what particular stored procs have inserted, updated and deleted after they were executed via Execute SQL task within a SSIS package workflow. There was a custom logging method that a 3rd party implemented, but it worked by relating a System ParentContainer ID to a user Task ID which served as a parameter to a stored procedure which logged such information. 1) I don’t think this will work from an Execute SQL Task and 2) I want a level of detail that extends past what DML function occurred.

I have been successful in logging a “single row” by setting up a result set, using variables and via an adjacent Data Flow task using a derived column task to retrieve the variables and insert into a log table.

As an example of my current working method:

The Exec SQL Task setup

Detail of the data flow part that logs

I am now coming across stored procedures that perform multiple inserts, thus I have the need to log the additional detail - more than one row. I created variables in the proc to retrieves this multiple INSERT scenario and have a union select in the SP that yields the following result set.

I understand that I now need to use the Full Result Set setting now but for this application what method is used for to persist the result set to another step (for me a destination in order to log). Amongst research I understand how one may use a Foreach loop container but this appears to configurable to one variable which needs to be value type object. I currently have 4 variables here and unable to setup as such in the Collection section of the Foreach object.

I would appreciate any insight in achieving this or suggestion to another method altogether.

many thanks in advance!

Comment: I find this question ambiguous and therefore unclear.  By the time you get to this:  "but I am puzzled in what method to take from there and how to log this" it is no longer clear exactly what you are talking about.   Can you edit your question down to just the essentials and focus on exactly what the question is without the unnecessary background noise?

Comment: please advise if the revision is satisfactory

Comment: No I still have no idea what you are trying to ask, sorry.

Comment: No idea? Really? Well thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT_B_BUDGET SQL task generates more than 1 row, you want to use Foreach Loop to catch the full result set, correct?

1. create a variable, LoopObject, data type as Object.
2. edit INSERT_B_BUDGET task,

   in General tab, change ResultSet to Full result set

   in Result Set tab, Variable Name as LoopObject.
3. add Foreach loop container after INSERT_B_BUDGET task, move your Logging 1 task into the container.

   in Collection tab, Enumerator, select Foreach ADO Enumerator, ADO object source variable as LoopObject, Enumeration mode, select Rows in the first table.

   in Variable Mappings, add your existing 4 variables.

Comment: This worked marvelously. It completed what I had previously had a conceptual understanding of; I didn't understand that the loop object var was the only var to be mapped in Exec SQLTask and my other, field variables mapped in the Foreach container. Your instructions were very clear, thank you kindly. As a application curiosity, does this method make sense in logging insight from procs? Have you used such a method for the same application or others?

Comment: If your SQL task and log table are on the same SQL Server, you can use insert directly, no need SSIS. If they are not on the same instance, SSIS will work. Please mask my answer as answered if it solves your problem. Thanks.

Comment: Got it, thank you again. I did, but got the following message I believe because I am not vested yet. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a profiler trace to track what procs are being executed. You should set up filters on the trace by database and user and use the SQLProfilerTSQL_SPs template.

Comment: I know what procs are being executed, its a matter of capturing (> 1 row)output in the result set by virtue of variables in the proc such as DECLARE @rows_insert INT etc.